# failing An ANT build file if the java program it's referring to throws an Exception

Tags: java, ant, failonerror

I have the following Ant target :

```
<target name="getArchiverStatus" depends="exportContent">
<java classname="com.test.cms.build.GetErrorCountForArchiver"  failonerror="true">
<classpath>
<pathelement location="${cs.home}/${env}/main/main.jar" /> 
<fileset dir="${cs.home}/${env}/lib" includes="*.jar" />
</classpath>
<arg value="${cs.url}" />
<arg value="${cs.username}" />
<arg value="${cs.password}" />
<arg value="${ucm.archive.name}" />
<arg value="${ucm.workflow.logs.dir}" />
</java>
</target>
```

I want that this particular target should fail terminating further execution of the build file when the java class GetErrorCountForArchiver has thrown an Exception.Even after using Failonerror= true the next target is getting executed...

Comment: Does the `com.test.cms.build.GetErrorCountForArchiver` return a non-zero exit code when an exception occurs?

Comment: A Java program doesn't throw an exception. It exits with a given status. 0 means success, and everything else means error. Make your Java program exit (with System.exit(int)) with a non-zero status, and your ant script will work.

Comment: I can't use System.exit as this shuts down the server on which I'm running the build file.

Comment: Use fork="true" to start the java program in another JVM. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

Comment: Maybe you can return a non zero value from your public static int main(String... args) instead.

Comment: i have already used Fork = true.Still even if the target getArchiverStatus class throws a runtime Exception the next target is geeting executed.i want the build to stop @ that point only and exit

Comment: To be crystal clear : you must use fork="true" **and** exit from the forked Java program with a non-zero status.

Comment: JB Nizet:Can You please elaborate on this as i'm new to this whole thing JAVA as well as ANT.

Comment: Make sure your Java program does System.exit(56) (or anything else but 0), and make sure you have fork="true" and failonerror="true" in your java task definition.

Comment: I tried returning 1 for unsuccessful execution but still the next target is getting executed and m not allowed to use System.exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you use the *fork=true* and *failonerror=true*. I was running into the same issue but after having those two properties set I got it working as I wanted.

I had simple class

```
package jonathanmv.tests;
public class ContinuousIntegration {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("This is supposed to happen");
    }
}
```

Then a simple ant build file

```
<project name="Continuous Integration Build" basedir="." default="main">

    <property name="package" value="jonathanmv.tests" />
    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes" />
    <property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar" />
    <property name="jar.file" value="${jar.dir}/${package}.jar" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />

    <property name="main-class" value="${package}.ContinuousIntegration" />

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>
    <path id="application" location="${jar.file}" />

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false" />
        <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
        <jar destfile="${jar.file}" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}" failonerror="true">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath" />
                <path refid="application"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar" />

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run" />

</project>
```

*clean-build* and *main* do not run because the *run* target fails due to the exception thrown by the main class. Notice that the following line is the one that does the trick in the *run* target

```
<!-- ... -->
<java fork="true" classname="${main-class}" failonerror="true">
<!-- ... -->
```

When I execute ant this is what I get

> Buildfile: /home/team/workspace/CI/trunk/build.xml
>
> clean:
>      [delete] Deleting directory /home/team/workspace/CI/trunk/build
>
> compile:
>       [mkdir] Created dir: /home/team/workspace/CI/trunk/build/classes
>       [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /home/team/workspace/CI/trunk/build/classes
>        [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/team/workspace/CI/trunk/build/classes
>
> jar:
>       [mkdir] Created dir: /home/team/workspace/CI/trunk/build/jar
>         [jar] Building jar: /home/team/workspace/CI/trunk/build/jar/jonathanmv.tests.jar
>
> run:
>        [java] Continuous Integration ran
>        [java] 0 [main] INFO jonathanmv.tests.ContinuousIntegration  - Continuous Integration > ran
>        [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: This is supposed to happen
>        [java]   at jonathanmv.tests.ContinuousIntegration.main(Unknown Source)
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   /home/team/workspace/CI/trunk/build.xml:41: Java returned: 1
>
> Total time: 1 second